# Window too large when moved to second display

Tags: macos, display

When I move a window from a larger display to a smaller display, sometimes it's so large that the bottom right hand corner is outside the display, meaning that I can't easily resize it.

What can I do about this situation?

Comment: Definitely see my answer. I created my solution for this exact situation. Now I add it to all computers I use and im able to switch from several monitors no problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in a `Keyboard Shortcut` using system preferences. I have mine to execute the `Zoom` option located under the `Window` tab at the top of most browsers and applications. I changed the `Command + Return + Shift` from the default to my new shortcut zoom.

This will resize the window to fit the screen and if a different/smaller screen size is desired, you can easily resize it using the corners from here.

It is actually much easier to resize from this resized/"Zoomed" window because moving your mouse to any of the computer screen's edges will place you directly over the edge of the window allowing you do resize the screen without mis-clicking (example of mis-clicking: causing another window/application to become active or moving the position/orientation of the window altogether).

Just add in the application you want this shortcut to work for under the `App Shortcuts` option within the "Keyboard" -> "Shortcuts" sections of system preferences.

As long as any part of the top of the window is visible, then the following will work:

```
Hold down "Shift" while double-clicking then the window's title bar. 
This will resize the window to fit your screen.
```

Comment: Like this one. Just to note you could also put it in the "All Apps" section, then it would work in any app with the Zoom menu item.

Comment: @Tetsujin indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, moving most windows from a large display to a smaller display automatically resized it to fit height-wise.

If it does not automatically do so, clicking the Green Maximize/Zoom button in the title bar should make it fit to the current screen/window content. If the application works with full screen mode, hold the Option key while clicking the button. From there you should have more access to resizing the window.

Note: You should also be able to resize an application's windows from any corner.

Edit: As per comment, this is also useful for resizing windows width-wise.

Comment: My problem was width-wise, not height-wise. But the Option + Green Maximize seems to work.

Comment: If the window is as described in the OP, then there are cases when the title bar is not visible. You would not be able to see the green, red, or yellow buttons at all.

Comment: @les I have not found a common way to make title bars go above the menu bar. If there is a common way to do so, please do tell. Also, the OP did mentioned _moving_ the window, and in all cases where I moved the window from my 24" display to my 15" screen, it automatically resized it to fit height-wise.

Comment: @NetherLinks Try unplugging the cable connecting the display and computer with Adobe Dreamweaver opened to max width & height on secondary display. It is the first application I tried. It is also not a height problem but a width problem. the buttons are not visible.

Comment: @les I don't have Dreamweaver, but I could not replicate your situation with Photoshop CS6. Seems a quirk of the application and not the system. However I agree with your answer for those weird cases.

Answer (score -1):

Most apps will also resize their window to fit your screen if you double-click anywhere on the top bar (title bar).

Comment: not firefox, not yosemite chrome. It depends, but if you hold down Shift while double-clicking then the window will fit to your screen